# Averaging Data from a file

Tags: java, file

I'm attempting to average each students grades from this file.  I have successfully listed the student names and their grades in the output of my code, but the final step is to output the average of the grades.  This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;         

public class Grades_Data
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 String filename = "student_data.txt";


  File file = new File("student_data.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {

     String firstName = inputFile.next();
     String lastName = inputFile.next();
     String gradeone = inputFile.next();
     String gradetwo = inputFile.next();
     String gradethree = inputFile.next(); 


     System.out.println("first name: " + firstName + "\tlast name: " + lastName + "\tgrade one: " + gradeone + 
     "\tgrade two: " + gradetwo + "\tgrade three: " + gradethree);
  }
  inputFile.close();
}
}
```

This is the output of my code:

```
first name: Willis  last name: McGee    grade one: 86   grade two: 91   grade three: 78
first name: Gladis  last name: Knight   grade one: 79   grade two: 93   grade three: 88
first name: John    last name: Wayne    grade one: 92   grade two: 89   grade three: 88
first name: Ginny   last name: Weasley  grade one: 68   grade two: 73   grade three: 89
```

I need it to say "average: " at the end of each line with the average grade of the student, using their grade one, grade two, and grade three values (the sum of the three grades divided by 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the string to int's (add them together divide by three)

```
int average = (Integer.parseInt(gradeOne) + Integer.parseInt(gradeTwo) + Integer.parseInt(gradeThree))/3;
```

add output to your string:

```
System.out.println("first name: " + firstName + "\tlast name: " + lastName + "\tgrade one: " + gradeone + 
     "\tgrade two: " + gradetwo + "\tgrade three: " + gradethree  + "\taverage: " + average);
```

Comment: This was what I needed.  I was unaware that I had to parse them together.  I had just tried to create a variable that added them all up and divided by three.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, in future when writing questions to SO write about a specific problem you are having, or why you can't get it to work, and show what you tried. If it was something more complex you might not get an answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
int average = ( Integer.parseInt(gradeone ) +  Integer.parseInt(gradetwo ) + Integer.parseInt(gradethree ) ) / 3;


  System.out.println("first name: " + firstName + "\tlast name: " + lastName + "\tgrade one: " + gradeone + 
     "\tgrade two: " + gradetwo + "\tgrade three: " + gradethree + "\taverage: " + average );
```

add this.
You need to parse your String vaues to Integer, and calculate the average

Comment: Looks like you both answered at the same time.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this
 System.out.println("first name: " + firstName + "\tlast name: " + lastName + "\tgrade one: " + gradeone + 
     "\tgrade two: " + gradetwo + "\tgrade three: " + gradethree 
**+"\tAverage: "+ (gradeone+gradetwo+gradethree)/3**
);

Comment: you need to parse the String values to int